# Operation on list in list of list using list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to print a list of tuples containing the size of each list from list of list

ex:

```
l=[1,3,4,5,6,7],[1,1],[1,9,9]

print(list(map(lambda x: ("sum",sum(1 for i in l)),l)))
```

- The output is coming as [('sum', 3), ('sum', 3), ('sum', 3)]

  I am trying to get it using list comprehension.
- The expected output I want    should be
  [('sum',6),('sum',2),('sum',3)]

Comment: Shouldn't `sum` show... the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug, it should be

```
sum(1 for i in x) # x, not l
```

Also, `len(x)` would give you the same number.

The list-comprehension solution is

```
[('sum', len(x)) for x in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```
l=[1,3,4,5,6,7],[1,1],[1,9,9]
nl= [("sum",len(lst)) for lst in l]
print(nl)
```

output:

```
[('sum', 6), ('sum', 2), ('sum', 3)]
```

if you have any question about the code feel free to ask me in the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is

```py
print(list(map(lambda x: ("sum",sum(1 for i in x)),l)))
```

The the mapping function has an agrument x, when you iterate over `l` to get the sum you are accessing the global `l` variable.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you want

```
l=[1,3,4,5,6,7],[1,1],[1,9,9]
print([('sum', len(l_)) for l_ in l])
```

Output:

```
[('sum', 6), ('sum', 2), ('sum', 3)]
```

But i think that is not **sum**, it's **len**, so:

```
l=[1,3,4,5,6,7],[1,1],[1,9,9]
print([('len', len(l_)) for l_ in l])
```

Output:

```
[('len', 6), ('len', 2), ('len', 3)]
```